# How to Auto-update a powerpoint presentation on another PC

Tags: batch-file, automation, powerpoint

I have 10 computers running a powerpoint presentation at 10 different sites.  These computers display the presentation on a flat screen television as our electronic menu board.

What i'd like to do is setup a script to auto upload the power point files each night so if a change has taken place we do not have to physically connect to each location.

I was thinking of making a basic batch file to send the powerpoint file via FTP commands. However, I have the following questions:

How can I close the presentation on the remote computer before I overwrite the current presentation, and how can I relaunch the presentation after the upload finishes?

Comment: Are these sites in the same windows domain?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this. The way your hinting at could be done as follows. Assuming you have high enough privileges.

1. Open the document form a network drive this makes it easier for you as you don't need to distribute copies. If they are in the same domain this should be easy to accomplish. As an alternative you could use ftp, but personally i would use something like robocopy or a rsync client like unison.
2. Kill the powerpoint task. You can do this with taskkill, using something like sc, psexec, telnet, ssh, rsh... or you could just use **wmic** as follows:

   ```
   wmic /node:computer process where name="powerpoint.exe" delete
   ```

   you can also directly control computers with the task scheduler so you could do all of the needed things with one batch from **Task Scheduler** as an alternative.
3. Restart the powerpoint with the new document if you save the presentation as a "Powerpoint Show" it will automatically fo to show mode; again you can use whatever but with wmic it would look as follows:

   ```
    wmic /node:computer process call create "pth\2\powerpoint.exe pth\2\f.pps"
   ```

rinse and repeat. Note that I don't have any powerpoint to test this on so hard to be super definitive. However i would do this with powershell and call the powerpoint COM API to load stuff as it can be more elegant.